# SQL Table selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create some means of dynamically selecting the table for a procedure to run on based on an ID sent to the database. Something like :

```
@TableId int
As

Declare @nameoftable varchar(50)

select @nameoftable = Nameoftable from tablelist where id = @tableid


-- returning on selected table

Select somestuff
from @nameoftable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL

```
@TableId int
As

Declare @nameoftable varchar(50)
select @nameoftable = Nameoftable from tablelist where id = @tableid

-- returning on selected table

declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
set @sql = 'Select somestuff from ' + Quotename(@nameoftable)
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid just executing a set piece of sql and just returing the value out of @nameoftable. Is there no other way of doing this?

Comment: You could use the above to actually do a check to see if the table exists (`IF EXISTS`) and then return either '[TABLENAME] Message to user confirming it exists' or '[TABLENAME] Message to user to alert them that the table doesn't exist'

Comment: Do you mean that `@nameoftable` should be the output of a SP for you to use? You can do that as en out parameter or as a result set.

Comment: @Dra no you cannot select against a table-name in a variable. If the proc returns you the table name (from id), then you run the dynamic sql outside the proc still using the last 3 lines from above

Answer (score 2):

In MS SQL Server you can use sp_executesql to execute dynamic queries. Read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), it helped me alot.